# Parse a JSON Array out of JSON String?

Tags: c#, json

Before marking this as duplicate, I'd like to say that I have my own implementation of a JsonObject and that is why I ask for guidance here.

I have been scratching my head at how to parse out one or more JSON Arrays from a JSON string. I have the following code:

```
class JsonObject
{
    public struct JsonProperty
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
    }

    public Dictionary<String, JsonProperty> Properties;

    public JsonObject()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<String, JsonProperty>();
    }

    public JsonObject(String jsonString)
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<String, JsonProperty>();
        ParseString(jsonString);
    }

    public JsonObject(List<String> properties)
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<String, JsonProperty>();
        foreach (String s in properties)
        {
            String[] keyvaluepair = s.Split(':');
            JsonProperty prop = new JsonProperty();
            prop.Name = keyvaluepair[0];
            prop.Value = keyvaluepair[1];

            Properties.Add(prop.Name, prop);
        }
    }

    public void AddProperty(String name, String value)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = new JsonProperty();
        prop.Name = name;
        prop.Value = value;

        Properties.Add(prop.Name, prop);
    }

    private void ParseString(String jsonString)
    {
        String[] splitByComma = jsonString.Split(',');
        List<String[]> splitByColon = new List<String[]>();
        foreach (String s in splitByComma)
        {
            String[] split = s.Split(':');
            splitByColon.Add(split);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < splitByColon.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < splitByColon[i].Length; j++)
            {
                splitByColon[i][j] = splitByColon[i][j].Replace(",", "");
                splitByColon[i][j] = splitByColon[i][j].Replace("}", "");
                splitByColon[i][j] = splitByColon[i][j].Replace("{", "");
                splitByColon[i][j] = splitByColon[i][j].Replace("\"", "");
                splitByColon[i][j] = splitByColon[i][j].Replace("\\", "");
                splitByColon[i][j] = splitByColon[i][j].Replace(":", "");
            }
        }

        foreach (String[] array in splitByColon)
        {
            JsonProperty p = new JsonProperty();
            p.Name = array[0];
            p.Value = array[1];
            Properties.Add(p.Name, p);
        }
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("{");
        int count = 1;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JsonProperty> p in Properties)
        {
            sb.Append("\"" + p.Key.ToString() + "\"");
            sb.Append(":" + p.Value.Value.ToString());
            if (count < Properties.Count)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            count++;
        }
        sb.Append("}");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

It works very well, but I might have designed myself into a corner, if I wanted to take on JSON Arrays. I could get a string that looks like this:

```
{"SSN":"300391-1453","LoanAmount":50000.0,"LoanDuration":"2015/02/02","CreditScore":550,"Receipients":[{"bankXML":"bankXML","bankJSON":"bankJSON","bankWeb":"bankWeb"]}
```

And I am clueless as to how I would properly take out that array, and how I would store it. My idea is that I locate the array and then parse out each object inside the array as a JsonProperty and then store all of the properties in a JsonArray with a name value.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a Javascript Serializer for moving between .NET objects and JSON?

Comment: @Hopdizzle I felt having concrete Json objects was just easier to manage if I wanted to add/remove properties from the string. I also couldn't control what the output was from the serializer and it caused a few issues.

Comment: @Vipar Existing serializer allows you to deserialize into Json objects too

Comment: @Vipar If you're using Newtonsoft library, you can use the [`JObject JObject.Parse(string json)`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start at [json.org](http://www.json.org/), which has (among other things) the JSON *grammar*. Then you write a *tokenizer* that reads a stream of characters and emits a stream of *tokens* (e.g, whitespace, number, string, colon, comma, square bracket (left/right), curly braces (left/right), etc. Then you write a *parser* to recognize the desired grammar and convert the various constructs into the desired representation.

Or you can use any of a number of pre-written JSON serialization tools.